# How to overwrite a default value in Views

Tags: django, django-views

I have several views which use the same model and template due to the need for unique urls.

Each view needs to set its own unique default values for several of the model's fields. For example in View 1, the models' field titled 'name' should have a default value of 'Name for a View 1 item', likewise 'Name for a View 2 item' under View 2 etc.

How would I specify / overwrite a default value for a field in a view?

For example

Models.py

```
class articles(models.Model):
    fk_collection = models.ForeignKey(collection, default='1' on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
```

Views.py

```
from .models import (articles)

class collection1(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = misc
    fields = ['fk_collection', 'name']
    template_name = 'books_collection1.html'

{would like default value of fk_collection to be '1', name to be 'new article for collection 1'}

class collection2(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = misc
    fields = ['fk_collection', 'name']
    template_name = 'books_collection1.html'

{would like default value of fk_collection to be '2', name to be 'new article for collection 2'}
```

the html file

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

<h1>Collection</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div>{{ form|crispy }}</div>
    </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done ?

Comment: could you show the views.py file?

Comment: Updated above in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can override `form_valid()` to set the value, for example through a base create view:

```
from .models import Article

class BaseArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = misc
    fields = ['name']
    fk_collection_value = None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_collection_id = self.fk_collection_value
        return super.form_valid(form)
```

Then you can subclass with the two views:

```
class Article1CreateView(BaseArticleCreateView):
    fk_collection_value = 1
    template_name = 'books_collection1.html'

class Article2CreateView(BaseArticleCreateView):
    fk_collection_value = 2
    template_name = 'books_collection2.html'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately the defaults are not being set, there are no errors however, the app works. I wonder if it has something to do with using crispy forms. I've updated my question to show the html file.

Comment: @GameAnalysis: you did not include the `fk_collection` in the `name` right? What if you se `fk_collection ` instead? You do subclass the `Article1CreateView` from the `BaseArticleCreateView`?

Comment: Do you mean in the fields of the parent class? Yes, it is copied, the subclass set up, no errors.